# Razor Page Call Modal From Code Behind on post async

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I read a barcode and save the user in the database by posting back once I read the code, while in the OnPostAsync I validate on the user and I want to show a popup window if the user renewal date is expired? so how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ajax to call `OnPostAsync` and then show a popup in ajax success.Here is a demo:

cshtml(you can put the data you want to pass into `data` of ajax):

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<button onclick="postdata()">submit</button>
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        function postdata() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '',
                headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
                data: { id: 1 }
            }).done(function (result) {
                if (result.message != "") {
                    alert("message:"+result.message);
                    }
                    
                });
                
        }
    </script>

}
```

cshtml.cs:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(int id)
        {
            //you can check if the user renewal date is expired here 
            if (id==1)
            {
                return new JsonResult(new{ message = "user renewal date is expired" });
            }
            else {
                return new JsonResult(new { message = "" });
            }
        }
```

result:
[image]